# Tricky Xor problem p(x) = x^(x/2) given p(x) find out value of x

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, xor, bitwise-xor

A project was going on related to image processing and to perform experiments and get desired result the image needs to be converted to Gray-Scale using a parameter 'x' and the function P(x) represented the Gray-Code and calculated via x xor (x div 2) where xor stands for bitwise exclusive OR (bitwise modulo 2 addition), and div means integer division.

It is interesting to note that function P(x) is invertible, which means it is always possible to uniquely restore x given the value of P(x).

So the group working on the project forgot to keep the original data related to parameter 'x'. Write a program to restore number x from the given value of P(x).

INPUT:
The input file contains an integer number y, the value of G(x).

OUTPUT:
The output file should contain a single integer x such that G(x) = y.

Sample Input:
15

Sample Output:
10

Can anyone clearly explain your solution's to this problem???

Comment: Yes, that does look like a tricky problem. So, what have you done to try to solve it? Since you're asking a question on Stack Overflow, I presume you've written some code but it's not working correctly. So, where's the code, and what's the nature of the problem with it?

Comment: I tried a lot to figure out the problem but couldn't succeed. So please give me the basic idea

Comment: The most significant bit set to 1 isn't affected by this operation. Knowing what the original value of *that* bit was, what does that allow you to deduce?

Answer (score 0):

I can't take credit for this, refer directly to https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gray_code